# Mac OS X version specific API usage

Tags: macos, xcode4.2, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard

As i am learning OS X development and here i came across strange situation where i need to find out a way to build the app for target above 10.6 and if it is 10.7 then i need to call some newly added methods or enums.  May be there is no such way but thought to ask it.

I guess there must be way to use it via Macros or something similar. I don't want to create OS specific builds. Any help will be appreciated. May be there is no such way but thought to ask it.

Regards,
M P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the version from the property file:

```
  /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
```

In this way, you can build dynamic code without different versions by #ifdefine

EDIT: @MP Well, I understood that you do not want to generate version specific code. **If** you ready to do so, then it is quite easy. Simply use:

```
  #include <Availability.h>
  #ifdef __MAC_10_7
      /* 10.7 only code */
  #else
      /* not 10.7 code */
  #endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So you mean with the help of i #ifdefine i can make use of 10.7 specific enum and methods and then compile it for target above 10.6? Any example of #ifdefine will be helpful.

Comment: Actually, you are not guaranteed to be able to use the __MAC_10_7 macro reliably for this purpose. While the current SDKs before 10.7 don't define this constant, the latest version of the 10.4 SDK defines __MAC_10_5 as well.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to compare `NSFoundationVersionNumber` with `NSFoundationVersionNumber10_*` -- see `Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h` for the available versions.

Sometimes, you can try `-[NSObject respondsToSelector:]`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out but i also have to make use of 10.7 enums so i guess i will have to use #ifdefine and then add methods those make use of those enums. Using if define, i goess will not generate compile time error.

Comment: @MP if you set the `SDKROOT` to 10.7, then you can build with those headers and enums visible.